# App browser icon strokes are inconsistent

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, ios-app

The stroke weight on the four icons at the bottom of the in-app browser are inconsistent.

> [image]

Back and forward are thick. Reload is medium. Share is thin. I propose they all match Share, which is the stock iOS icon, but most important is they match intrinsically.

First world problems.

Comment: Reload is actually built-in, so it's brought to you by the same people that gave you share.   I guess they never envisioned it in that context?  Those arrows are way too thick though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS9, we've switched to SFSafariViewController in most places so I'm just going to let this screen die a slow death without improvements.